# Include "resources" folder when publishing application using Clickonce method

Tags: c#, resources, clickonce, publish

I have various files added into resources and during debugging these files are being copied to output directory but when I publish the app, the resource folder is appearing in the "application files" however only the pictures (.png) files have been included.

I would essentially like to have the remaining files (xml, msi, exes) part of the application files

Appreciate it if someone can shed some light

Comment: What are the `Build Settings` for those files? Have you set them in `Application Files` to be included?

Comment: What you mean by `Build Settings`? I have checked in `Application Files` but can't see them or add. I however was wondering do I need to convert the exe's to .DLL in order to see them ? if yes how about the remaining.

Comment: Every File has Settings witch you can set to: Compile, Build Resource, ... Try playing with those and compile before looking in `Application Files` if they appear there after that.